# key stroke interrupt in cygwin

Tags: c, linux, windows, cygwin

I'm using cygwin in windows 7. I have a function which does something in while(1) continuously. I want to have interrupt when there is a input from keyboard. I get blocked if i use scanf inside while(1). I installed ncurses in cygwin and tried using ncurses.h to use getch() function which will not block the while(1). But I get errors like:

[image]

I serached and installed some additional libraries like libxerces-c and libxerces-c-devel. But still didn't work. Anyone help please.

```
while (1) {
    if (getch() == 'q')
       break; 
    display_time();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share some code illustrating your problem

Comment: my main code looks like this. 
while(1) {
    if (getch() == 'q')
         break;
    display_time();
}

Actually i'm planning to do digital watch code. So when there is input "m" i need to go to stop watch mode. till i receive "m", it should display time.

Comment: Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details on what a question should contain. What is the command you use to build your program? Most likely you're missing a `-lncurses`.

Comment: Have you used cygwin setup to install the `ncurses` and `libncurses-devel` packages. You can probably uninstall `libxerces-c` and `libxerces-c-devel` unless you need them for other reasons. You might find the `ncurses-demo` package helpful.